# Is it possible for the apple watch app to know that it was launched using Complication interface?

Tags: swift, apple-watch, watchos, apple-watch-complication

I am writing a simple app with several controllers.
After running the app using Complication interface I would like to skip main view controller and immediately pass to the second one. I know how to perform this action, but have no idea how to get the info that the app was launched using Complication. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement the `handleUserActivity(_ userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)` of the `WKExensionDelegate` to check if the app was launched from the complication. You would also probably want to take a look at the [CLKComplicationDataSource Protocol Reference Launch Options](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/ClockKit/Reference/CLKComplicationDataSource_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Launch_Options) for information on the userInfo passed to `handleUserActivity`